# How do I define a function that removes the smallest value of x from a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to define a function which will remove values that are either x or smaller then x from a list

I've tried to done this so far, but with haven't been able to perform a people solution:

```
Value = int(input(”Pick a value”: )
L_List = [1, 2, 3, 4]

Def rem(L_list, value):
    Count = 0
    For i in list:
        If L_list[i] > value
            Return L_List[i]
        Else: 
            Return L_List.Remove[i]

Print(rem(L_list, value))
```

So if the user pick e.g. 3

The function should print out a new list:

List = [4]

Hope some one can explain how I should do it

Comment: please format your code, why does every line start with a capital letter? also do you understand what `return` does? it **stops** the function while returning the value

Comment: Also, note that Python is case-sensitive as well as indentation matters.

Comment: Please post code that actually runs.  This code is full of syntax errors and undefined variables.

Comment: @Sebastian, do check how I have edited the code block. please try to put your code with such indentations for subsequent questions/answers.

Comment: Also, as indicated by previous comments, this seems more like a pseudo code rather than actual python code, since the syntax is quite far from actual. It's better to write a running code and ask for assistance with errors, rather than just a code skeleton.

Comment: Thank you @Aksay I will do that instead of

Comment: @Matiis no I'm not totally sure, I've started on python 2 weeks ago and learning day by day.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. Try this and explore this line by line -

```
Value = int(input("Pick a value:"))
L_List = [1, 2, 3, 4]

output = []

for i in L_List:
    if i>Value:
        output.append(i)
    
print(output)
```

```
Pick a value:2
[3, 4]
```

---

A more pythonic way would be to use list comprehension

```
Value = int(input("Pick a value:"))
L_List = [1, 2, 3, 4]

output = [i for i in L_List if i>Value]
print(output)
```

```
Pick a value:2
[3, 4]
```